# MySQL if cell equals this then use number, else zero

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have an SQL statement that looks like the following:

```
SELECT  each_req.serial_num,
        each_req.sponsors,
        each_req.subscription_code,
        format(sum(trans.trans_data-ifnull(trans.trans_prev,0))/3600,2) as hours,
        each_req.subject
        FROM   each_req,
               transactions AS trans
        WHERE  trans.serial_num = each_req.serial_num
               AND trans.type != 'priority'
               AND trans.actor LIKE 'username'
               AND trans.trans_date > unix_timestamp('2015-07-29 00:00:00')
               AND trans.trans_date < unix_timestamp('2015-07-29 14:22:03')
        GROUP BY each_req.serial_num
```

The problem is that the `trans.trans_prev` and `trans.trans_data` has a mix of data types based on what kind of `trans.trans_type` it is.

I have the line `format(sum(trans.trans_data-ifnull(trans.trans_prev,0))/3600,2) as hours,` in my SQL statement. I essentially want this to equal `0` if `trans.trans_type != 'time_worked'`.

I already have an `ifnull` check in there, however I am unclear how I can add an `if` statement that will compare against the columns data.

Comment: Can't you use a `CASE` statement there?

Comment: @bleh yes I am not opposed to using a CASE statement if it would work better than a if statement

Comment: If you just have the if ... else ... situation you can use IF(), if you have a if ... else if  ... else ... then use CASE. see here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: @paulF I didn't really know `IF()` even existed. Would this look something like `IF(expression) as 'hours'`?

Comment: @PaulF well it should just be one case. If type = time_worked then do this calculation, otherwise it is just 0.

Comment: IF(trans.trans_type != 'time_worked',0, format(sum(trans.trans_data-ifnull(trans.trans_prev,0))/3600,2)) as hours.

Comment: @PaulF now all of the results are returning 0.

Comment: Without seeing the data it's hard to know what is wrong - I have done some quick checks on case-sensitivity, trailing spaces, underscore as special char (it is with LIKE) - and cannot get it to fail to work correctly. The only oddity is if the column is null - then IF always returns false regardless of check if equal or not equal to a string. NOTE - my table is InnoDB & collation is utf8_general_ci - othe table types/collations may work differently - so you could try trimming and converting to lower case.

Comment: @PaulF I got this to work for me: `FORMAT(SUM(IF(trans.type != 'time_worked',0, trans.trans_data-ifnull(trans.trans_prev,0)))/3600, 2) as hours,`